# Update Object in 2D Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

I currently have the following code below and I want to update the specific place in the 2D array with an X and then re-print the board. I am currently stuck where I need to update the object in the array to an X but I keep getting:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Ship
```

What am I doing wrong? I have already placed all the objects on the board.

```
public void updateBoard(int row, int column, Ocean ocean){
    //get ship array
    Ship[][] sea = ocean.getShipArray();
    //mark the x/y co-ordinate with X 
    sea[row][column] = "X"; // PROBLEM  
    // print the board
}
```

I have included the Ship Class

```
public abstract class Ship {
// TODO add appropriate comments
@Getter
private int size;
private String type;
private String shortForm;

// TODO add appropriate comments
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
private int bowRow;
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
private int bowColumn;
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
private boolean horizontal;

/**
 * An array of boolean which indicates whether that part of the ship has
 * been hit. This is initialised by the appropriate sub-class. Battleships
 * use all 4 locations; cruisers use the first 3; destroyers 2; submarines
 * 1; and "empty sea" 1.
 */
protected boolean[] hit;


/**
 * clears the hit array indicating whether that part of the "Ship" has been
 * hit
 */
protected Ship(int size, String type, String shortForm) {
    this.size = size;
    this.setType(type);
    this.shortForm = shortForm;
    hit = new boolean[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < hit.length; i++)
        hit[i] = false;
}

/**
 * Checks that ship of this size will not overlap another ship, or touch
 * another ship (vertically, horizontally, or diagonally) and that ship will
 * not "stick out" beyond the array.
 * 
 * @param row
 *            that will contain the bow
 * @param column
 *            that will contain the bow
 * @param horizontal = true if horizontal
 * @param ocean
 * @return true if it is okay to put a ship of this size with its bow in
 *         this location, with the given orientation.
 */
public boolean okToPlaceShipAt(int row, int column, boolean horizontal,
        Ocean ocean) {
    // Try to catch exception error if ship goes past board
    try{
        Ship ships[][] = ocean.getShipArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++){
        if (!(ships[row][column] instanceof EmptySea)){ 
        //  System.out.println("Cant Print here + " + row + column + getSize());
                return false;
        }else{
            if (horizontal) {
                column++; 
            } else {
                row++;  
            }
        //  System.out.print(ships[row][column]);

            }
    //  System.out.println(" ");

        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception err){
    //  System.out.println("OMG an error");
        return false;
    } 



}

/**
 * "places" the ship in the ocean, assigning values to the bowRow,
 * bowColumn, and horizontal. Places a reference to the ship in the ships
 * array in the Ocean object.
 * 
 * @param row
 *            to contain the bow
 * @param column
 *            to contain the bow
 * @param horizontal
 * @param ocean
 */
public void placeShipAt(int row, int column, boolean horizontal, Ocean ocean) {

    this.setBowRow(row);
    this.setBowColumn(column);
    this.setHorizontal(horizontal);

    Ship ships[][] = ocean.getShipArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
        // set position in array to contain the ship
        ships[row][column] = this;
        if (horizontal) {
            column++;
        } else {
            row++;
        }
    }
}

private int getSize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return size;
}

private void setHorizontal(boolean horizontal2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    horizontal = horizontal2;
}

private void setBowColumn(int column) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bowColumn = column;
}

private void setBowRow(int row) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bowRow = row;
}

/**
 * If this ship has been hit, marks that part of the ship as "hit"
 * 
 * @param row
 *            User's supplied row shot
 * @param column
 *            User's supplied column shot
 * @return true if ship is hit, false otherwise
 */
public boolean shootAt(int row, int column) {
    if ((isHorizontal() && (row != getBowRow()))
            || (!isHorizontal() && (column != getBowColumn())))
        return false; // it's not a hit

    // it's a hit. Work out offset & set that position in hit array to true
    hit[(row - getBowRow() + column - getBowColumn())] = true;

            return true;
}

private int getBowRow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bowRow;
}

private int getBowColumn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bowColumn;
}

private boolean isHorizontal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

/**
 * checks whether this ship is sunk - using the hit array
 * 
 * @return true if every part of the ship has been hit, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isSunk() {

    for (boolean b : hit)
        if (!b)
            return false;

    return true;
}


/**
 * @return a single character String to use in Ocean's print method
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return shortForm;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String setHit(String hit){
    return hit;
}
```

}

It is a bit long. 
Below is a sample of one if the ships that extends Ship, the Submarine class. All the others are exactly the same except for their sizes.

```
/*
 * A Battleship class which extends ship
 * Four Submarines in the game Length 1
 */
package Battleships;
public class Submarine extends Ship {
    private final static int SIZE = 1;
    /**
     * sets the length & clears the hit array
     */
    public Submarine() {
        super(SIZE, "Submarine", "S");
    }
}
```

Comment: error says it all you can't convert `String` object to `Ship` object

Comment: If you representing a ship by "X", use a String array instead of Ship array

Comment: the getShipArray is actually getting the board that has all the pieces on it and I am just trying to replace the one piece with an X. I hope this explains more.

Comment: Well, from the class declarator `public abstract class Ship` we can see that we can't directly create Ships. (`abstract` classes can't be directly instantiated). What we have to do now, is find which classes `extend Ship` as those will be the ones we can actually create. Based on this comment `Battleships use all 4 locations; cruisers use the first 3; destroyers 2; submarines 1; and "empty sea" 1.` I'm guessing that there are files with names along the lines of `Battleship, Submarine, Cruiser, and Destroyer`? If so, could you also post the Constructor for one of those? We will be needing them.

Comment: One other question actually. What are you trying to do with this line of your original code `//mark the x/y co-ordinate with X sea[row][column] = "X"; // PROBLEM` Are you firing a shot at (row,column)? Trying to place a ship there?

Comment: For your above comment, I have fired a shot there and there is a ship in that spot and want to now place an X there on the board to mark that it has been shot at and there is a ship there. I have uploaded the Submarine class.

Comment: See my updated answer. I don't believe you're trying to change the value of `sea[row][column]`, but rather to call the `Ship.shootAt(int,int)` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sea` is a `Ship[][]`, `"X"` is a `String`. You can't place a `String` in a variable that holds `Ship`.

Edit:

Since you're trying to shoot at a ship, rather than place a new ship, I suspect what you actually need is to use the following function from ship...

`public boolean shootAt(int row, int column)`.

From the code for Ship, I'm guessing what you actually need to do is...

`sea[row][column].shootAt(row,column);`

Comment: OK but how would I change the value of `sea[row][column]` which currently has an "S" in it to "X" bearing in mind that the "S" is an object that I placed at that spot `sea[row][column]`. From what I understand it is an object Ship as apposed to a String, Char or int.

Comment: You'd need to create an `X` ship object. Add the source code for `Ship` (especially the constructor) to your question, otherwise we have no clue what it is or how they're constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Special Ship and let it represent an 'X'. As per your updated question you can create a new ship as follows:

```
sea[row][column] = new Ship(1,"Cthulu","X");
```

Now whenever you print the Ship you will see an 'X' as the toString() method of class Ship returns the shortForm string value.

You can also extend the Ship class with your own toString() method in order to have a truly *different* kind of ship that represents an X.

Comment: This cannot be an answer, as of now as you do not know about the structure of Ship class. It may not have a constructor of the type you specified.

Comment: The constructor could be very very likely incorrect. But the basic idea of what he COULD do to solve his problem is listed above it. Ideally there's a static variable in the Ship class / a class that extends Ship that represents an X.

Comment: The above example gives me an error of "Cannot instantiate the type Ship". there are Ships in the Sea already and they extend the class Ship. I am just trying to replace the value in the 2D array to the character "X" or string "X".

Comment: An array of Ship's can only contain other ships. That is the basic rule that we all must follow. So you need to create a fake ship that represents an X or you need to change your entire program.

Comment: You can create another object that extends Ship and in its toString() method just print out an 'X'?  This is a very simple problem that you are having and there are multiple ways to solve it.

Comment: Sanchit, I think I will have to do it that way, but creating another object and placing an X in it.

Comment: Hi Sanchit, I went with your suggestion and it worked. I created another object that extends Ship and modified the details in there and it works.

Comment: Excellent! Let me edit my answer as well then. You can mark it as 'correct' if you feel like it. Glad that my suggestion helped!